# want to fetch user detail through DotNetOpenID

Tags: asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I am using DotOpenID and I want to fetch user's nickname and email ID

for request

```
 protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!openidValidator.IsValid) return; // don't login if custom validation failed.  
    OpenID(openid_identifier.Text);
}

private void OpenID(string Indentifier)
{
    OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
    try
    {
        IAuthenticationRequest request = openid.CreateRequest(Indentifier);
        // Send your visitor to their Provider for authentication.  
        ClaimsRequest fetch = new ClaimsRequest();
        fetch.FullName = DemandLevel.Require;
        fetch.Email = DemandLevel.Require;
        request.AddExtension(fetch);
        request.RedirectToProvider();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // The user probably entered an Identifier that   
        // was not a valid OpenID endpoint.  
        openidValidator.Text = ex.Message;
        openidValidator.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

and for response

```
 openid_identifier.Focus();
    OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
    if (openid.Response != null)
    {
        switch (openid.Response.Status)
        {
            case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:

                string email = "";
                string alias = "";

                ClaimsResponse fetch = openid.Response.GetExtension(typeof(ClaimsResponse)) as ClaimsResponse;
                alias = fetch.Nickname;
                email = fetch.Email;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(alias))
                    alias = openid.Response.ClaimedIdentifier;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                    email = openid.Response.ClaimedIdentifier;


                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(openid.Response.ClaimedIdentifier, chkRememberMe.Checked);
                break;
            case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
                loginCanceledLabel.Visible = true;
                break;
            case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
                loginFailedLabel.Visible = true;
                break;

        }
    }
```

but I am getting exception at here "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

```
 ClaimsResponse fetch = openid.Response.GetExtension(typeof(ClaimsResponse)) as ClaimsResponse;
                alias = fetch.Nickname;
                email = fetch.Email;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly duplicate:
[claimsResponse Return Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326505/claimsresponse-return-null)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265678/dotnetopenid-claimsresponse-always-null

The first one has the following answer by Andrew Arnott, which might be related:

> It looks like you're doing everything
>   right. At this point it depends on the
>   Provider you're using. Which one are
>   you testing against? Some don't
>   support Simple Registration
>   (ClaimsRequest) at all. Others only
>   support it for whitelisted RPs. Then
>   others don't support it when your RP
>   is at "localhost".
>
> My advice: test against myopenid.com,
>   as that seems to have good, consistent
>   behavior and support for the Simple
>   Registration extension. But your RP
>   must always be prepared to receive
>   null for ClaimsResponse, since you're
>   never guaranteed the OP will give you
>   anything.
>
> Even if you get a non-null result,
>   individual fields that you asked for
>   (even if you marked them required) may
>   be null or blank.